# htaccess redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

Google says that the content is duplicated
www.example.com/pagedcontent/page3 /
www.example.com/pagedcontent/page3

I redirected using redirect 301 for each page, but as they are already more than 150 pages would like to use a single instruction in the htaccess.

How to do? Please
I want to redirect to www.example.com/pagedcontent/page3 (without / at end)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063894/remove-trailing-slashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pagedcontent/([A-Za-z0-9]*)/$ /pagedcontent/$1 [NC]
```

That will remove the trailing slash for any page under pagedcontent.

You can also use the canonical meta tag, which is a way of specifying the original copy of the page. Put a meta tag in the head of your page like so:

Google will know that all other duplicates of this page are copies of it.