# 301 from mobile=N in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I wanted to make a 301 from URL with ?mobile=N parameter to URL without that parameter. Google is indexing this URL and I think that 301 is the best way to fix that

eg.

FROM

www.example.com/?mobile=N

TO

www.example.com

FROM

www.example.com/example/example.com?mobile=N

TO

www.example.com/example/example.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect 301](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041525/htaccess-redirect-301)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mobile=N$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```