# Remove trailing slash in wordpress blog URL

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I decided to use wordpress to power my blog section. I created a folder under my root directory of my site titled blog. Now when I visit http://trekeffect.dev/blog I get redirected to http://trekeffect.dev/blog/ with the trailing slash. How can I remove the trailing slash?

.htaccess inside blog folder is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

.htaccess i am using in my project rrot folder is

```
RewriteRule ^blog/$ /blog [R=301]
```

Any help will be really appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Mod_dir will automatically redirect any request for a directory that doesn't end with a trailing slash. This is because there's a security loophole that allows anyone to see the contents of a directory by *leaving the trailing slash off*. You can, of course, turn off this feature, but then you'd need to ensure you prevent this from happening by yourself. So something like this in your vhost config:

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L]
```

Not sure if this will work in an htaccess file because when someone goes to "`/blog`", they're already bypassing any rules in your document root and the slash/noslash issue can't be dealt with by then.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers add a trailing slash because of recent history, clear you history and try again. You could also try in a different browser.

A similar question has already been asked:

[Remove trailing slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063894/remove-trailing-slashes?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered here: [Remove trailing slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063894/remove-trailing-slashes?rq=1)

However, it must be said that keeping the trailing slash would be your best bet for SEO/UX, as including the trailing slash improves page load time, which is a factor in SE rankings and in positive user experience.

#### How including the trailing slash improves page load time:

- [webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/f/why-urls-end-in-slash.htm](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/f/why-urls-end-in-slash.htm)
- [searchenginejournal.com/linking-issues-why-a-trailing-slash-in-the-url-does-matter/13021/](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/linking-issues-why-a-trailing-slash-in-the-url-does-matter/13021/)
- [netmechanic.com/news/vol4/load_no11.htm](http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol4/load_no11.htm)

#### How page load time improves rankings (and conversion rates):

- [seobythesea.com/2009/07/does-page-load-time-influence-seo/](http://www.seobythesea.com/2009/07/does-page-load-time-influence-seo/)
- [moz.com/community/q/does-page-load-time-affect-seo-rankings](http://moz.com/community/q/does-page-load-time-affect-seo-rankings)
- [mattcutts.com/blog/site-speed/](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/site-speed/)
- [glennfriesen.com/page-load-time-affects-ux-rankings-and-your-cash-flow/](http://glennfriesen.com/page-load-time-affects-ux-rankings-and-your-cash-flow/)